# Running code in the proper order in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, promise

I'm making a site that compiles articles based on user interests. And I have a backend but I can't get the code to run in the right order basically I have a MongoDB database with users and each user has an email and an array of interests. The code starts by looping through the users then it loops through the interests and adds a certain amount of articles to recommend for each interest. But I need to return this data back to the client after I'm done looping through all of the interests but I can't find a way to do this.
code:

```
  //? Get user emails and intrests
  UsersReference.find({}).toArray(function (err, users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      const user = users[i]
      //? Generate a text blurb for user based off there intresets
      var limit = 10 / user.intrests.length
      for (var j = 0;j < user.intrests.length;j++) {
        axios({
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "https://tidalwaves-news-analytics2.p.rapidapi.com/articles?limit=" + limit,
          "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "tidalwaves-news-analytics2.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "SECRET",
            "useQueryString": true
          },
          "data": {
            "url": {
              "query": user.intrests[j]
            },
          }
        }).then((res) => {
          for(var l =0;l < res.data.data.length;l++) {
            blurbs[i] = blurbs[i] + ". " + res.data.data[l].title
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that your loop includes asynchronous calls.  One very good solution - as you noted in your tags and showed in your example - is to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  SUGGESTED CHANGE: instead of ".then()", use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for *ALL* information for a *SINGLE* user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `then()` to wait for promise fulfillment, you can wrap your logic in an `async` function and use the `await` keyword.

It would make your code easier to read and it would fix your issue.

Example:

```
async function myFunction() {
  for (const item of items) {
    const result = await axios({...});
    // Do something with `result`....
  }
}
```